# Take variable from a Python file and display in Flask

Tags: python, jquery, firebase, flask, firebase-realtime-database

OK so I am still struggling on this one, here is my complete code after using @DrAgon suggestion. I have 3 files, the first one is my Python file that merely get the local time.

```
import datetime
import time

now = datetime.datetime.now()

print(now)
```

If I set this file up as:

```
import datetime
import time

while True:
now = datetime.datetime.now()

print(now)
time.sleep(2)
```

It refreshes and gets me the date every 2 seconds but when it's imported in to my flask project it takes over and just will not load the web page.

so I use the first version of the file that gets the local time. Next I have my flask Python page:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
import Timereppper

import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)

@app.route('/')

def hello():
return render_template('hello.html', myvar= now.second)

@app.route('/currentstatus')

def currentstatus():
return render_template('hello.html', myvar= now.second)

@app.route('/historic')

def historic():
return render_template('historic.html')

@app.route('/data')
def get_data():
mbdata = Timereppper.now()  # Call your code that gets the data here
return jsonify(mbdata)  # And return it as JSON


if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(host= 'localhost', port=5000, debug=False, threaded=True)
```

and then i have my main hello.html file with the code suggested by @DrAgon at the bottom. This returns the text on the bottom of the main webpage "New Data Goes Here" and if I look at lcalhost:5000/data I get the date that was read at the when the flask server was first started. I want this date to update continuously or every few seconds and display on the main home page of the website. Can anyne show me where I am going wrong. I apologise I am new to flask.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Vibration Monitor</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-wi dth, initial-scale=1">
<link href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" 
rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') 
}}">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="{{
url_for('static', filename='jquery.js') }}">\x3C/script>')</script>
</head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-#808080">
<a class="navbar-brand" href= https://www.iotindustries.co.uk>
<img src="/static/img/IOT Industries Logo 1THIN.png" width="300" height="90" 
class="d-inline-block" alt="">
</a>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
<ul class="navbar-nav">
<li class="nav-item active">
<a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="/currentstatus">Current 
Status</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item active">
<a class="nav-link font-weight-bold" href="/historic">Historic</a>
</li>

</ul>
</nav>

<div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert"></div>

<div class="card-deck" style="width: 42rem;">

<div class="card text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="width: 16rem;">
<img class="card-img-top" src="/static/img/vibes1.png" alt="Vibration 
Image">
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-title">Current vibration level:</h5>
<h1 class="card-text font-weight-bold">15 mA</h1>
<a class="btn btn-success">Acknowledge</a>
</div>
</div>


<div class="card text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="width: 16rem;">
<img class="card-img-top" src="/static/img/timer.svg" alt="Timer Image">
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-title">Estimated days until failure:</h5>
<h1 class="card-text font-weight-bold"> 3 Days {{myvar}} </h1>
<a class="btn btn-info" href="/historic">View Historic</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<body>
<div id="myDataDiv">New Data Goes Here</div>
</body>
<script>
var goGetNewData = function() {
$.ajax({
url: '/data',
dataType: 'json',
type: 'get',
success: function(e) {
$('#myDataDiv').html('New Data ' + e);
},
error: function(e) {
$('#myDataDiv').html('Error');
},
});
}
var waitTime = 10;  // 10 seconds
var fetchInterval = window.setInterval(goGetNewData, waitTime*1000);
</script>


</html>
```

I have a Python file which is constantly reading a Modbus register every couple of seconds, using the Python sleep.() function. This value is getting logged to a google FireBase database.

What I would like to do is display this value read from the ModBus register on my Flask website. I just don't know how to do it. Am I able to either:

1. Get the updated ModBus value from the Python file, pass that in to "MyFlaskApp.py" continuously or at the click of a button in my HTML file.
2. Query the Firebase database and get this to display the latest written value either continuously or at the click of a button.

Which, if any of these, can be done and what would be the best method. Can anyone post an example of how I would be able to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to display the updated value on your HTML file continuously, without having to refresh the page? If so, you can listen for changes in a script on your HTML page, as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45024326/realtime-update-between-firebase-and-html-table

Comment: I think this method should work if I am constantly reading the data from the disease database. I am assuming this will update the data in the browser without having to refresh?

Comment: It might be easier to answer if you could post how the script looks. The one where the variable you want to read is.

Comment: @Luis Orduz, I have uploaded my code with an explanation of what i am trying to achieve. Please let me know how this could be done. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well If you want to do it on a click of a button, you can make the button part of an html form and have it post to your flask application:

```
@app.route('/update')
    def val():
        return render_template("index.html",data=data)
```

This would work, considering the value you want to pass to the html is called data.
To display the data passed through, your html should look like this:

```
<p>{{data}}</p>
```

Instead of updating the modbus value every two seconds, you could do it only when the button is clicked like so:

```
@app.route('/update')
def val():
   #code to get the value
   return render_template("index.html",data=data)
```

This way everytime you click the form button to get a new value, then the data is read from the database. Instead of using another file as an import and using datetime, this would make sure that your program not only saves memory but still returns the desired value. 
In the now method, you should write to a txt file as such:

```
#get the data
f = open("mod.txt", w+)
f.write(data)
f.close
```

Then when you recive the button click in the flask app:

```
@app.route('/update')
    def val():
        f = open("mod.txt",r)
        data = f.read()
        f.close()
        return render_template("index.html",data=data)
```

To make sure that the other program is running you can do this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    execfile('modbusreginfo.py')
    app.run(host= 'localhost', port=5000, debug=False, threaded=True)
```

If you want to make the page reload every 2 seconds so there is no button click you can add this to your html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="2">
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is essentially what I am trying to do, however it is getting that variable data in to the "myflaskapp.py" file that I am struggling with. For example, i have the python file that is reading the modbus register "modbusreginfo.py" within this file I have a variable "data" that is being read from the my modbus register. How do i then take that variable from "modbusreginfo.py" and get it in to "myflaskapp.py"?

Comment: I can think of a few ways of doing this, when your app starts you could execfile('modbusreginfo.py') and then modify the modbus file to write to a text file and parse that in my flask app, another way you could do this is instead of updating constantly in a different file, you can update the data only when the button is clicked. I will respond to this if I can think of another way.

Comment: @PrimitiveSource Do you need any clarification?

Comment: Hi @Arnav Chawla, please see the code in my updated question. Can you explain how I would use your text file method in this code?

Comment: @PrimitiveSource can you please post what your modbus file looks like, I am editing my answer right now with another possible solution.

Comment: please just consider the "now" variable from my Timereppper file as the variable in my ModBus file that I would like to bring in to Flask.

Comment: thank you for this, this solution works, a constant live update would be nice, if I could get it page to refresh automatically. I appreciate your input on this one!

Comment: Would be fine if the page updates every couple of seconds?

Comment: @PrimitiveSource I updated my answer for auto refresh therefore removing the button click

Comment: Perfect, thank you Arnav. I really appreciate all your help with this. Maybe you could help with this other issue I am currently having with displaying the value in flask. When I read the .csv file and display the value in my web browser it comes in as ['My Value'] i just want it to display as My Value, no brackets or speech marks. Any ideas? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52078062/flask-python-csv-variable-shown-as-text-not-text

Comment: Yes, I would love to help but unfortunately that question has been flagged as duplicate . Should I just update my answer here

Comment: yes if you could update the answer here that would be great. The duplicate post they have linked me to is not correct. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way.

You will need to create 2 routes in your MyFlaskApp.py

1. /home - This route will render an HTML template
2. /data - This route will return JSON (containing the data from your ModBus file OR from querying Firebase)

(you can name the routes whatever you want)

In the HTML template returned by the first route you will need a div (with an id) to render the data and some JavaScript to continuously fetch new data.

Then just point the Ajax GET at your /data endpoint and your on your way.

```html
<body>
<div id="myDataDiv">New Data Goes Here</div>
</body>
<script>
var goGetNewData = function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/data',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'get',
    success: function(e) {
       $('#myDataDiv').html('New Data ' + e);
    },
    error: function(e) {
      $('#myDataDiv').html('Error');
    },
  });
}
var waitTime = 10;  // 10 seconds
var fetchInterval = window.setInterval(goGetNewData, waitTime*1000);
</script>
```

The /data route could look something like this.

```
from flask import jsonify
import Modbusreginfo  # Import your other python code

@app.route('/data')
def get_data():
  mbdata = Modbusreginfo.getModBusData()  # Call your code that gets the data here
  return jsonify(mbdata)  # And return it as JSON
```

Comment: if for example I use this method to get the "mbdata" variable from my "Modbusreginfo.py" file, how would I include this in the code you have supplied. I think this method is looking like the simplest solution.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how you could integrate with your Modbusreginfo file. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello again @DoctorAgon, I feel I am getting closer. I like the look of this solution but I am still struggling with the python file. Just t simplify things, I am using the datetime and using the datetime string as my variable. First I was fetching the date and time with while True: print(now) time.sleep(2). I then import this file to my MyFlaskApp.py and ran the code as above, if I go to localserver:5000/data I can see the datetime, but then the browser just freezes up and wont refresh, I think this is due to the time.sleep(2) taking over.

Comment: So I got rid of the time.sleep(2) and while True and the code runs ok, but only gets the date once and doesn't continuously update. The HTML code doesn't display anything other than "new data goes here", do I need to change anything in the HTML code you have posted? I have also tried updating the date value using app scheduler, when I run this code in the python file on its own it works OK, as soon as I import this module to my flask file, it says Pythn can find the apscheduler model. I will keep trying, let me know where I am going wrong. Thanks

Comment: So if you would like the webpage to automatically reload, you'll need to do that from the client (browser) side. Add `window.setTimeout(location.reload(), timeout*1000);` to have the page reload after `timeout` seconds

Comment: One other thing, it is generally considered best practice to place all imports at the top of the file. Having the import statement inside a function, or worse a loop, will cause the module to be imported multiple times.

Comment: Hi @DoctorAgon. I have uploaded my complete code. It is still isn't doing what I am expecting. Please could you take a look and see if you can work out where I am going wrong. I have simplified it so that I am just getting the current daytime.

Comment: Try removing the `while True:` from the Timereppper file.